# CSS Height of Table Exceeds Height of Body

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a table as a replacement for an image map so that it can be responsive, but for some reason, after setting the table's height to 100%, it still goes past the body, and I can't figure out why.

CSS and HTML:

```
        body, 
        html {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color:black;
        }

        html {
            background-color:white;
        }

        table {
            border-spacing:0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            height:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        td {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            height:100%;
        }

        tr {
            height:100%;
        }

        <table>
            <tr data-name="row1">
                <td data-name="pic1">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/A1-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/A1-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td data-name="pic2">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/B1-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/B1-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-name="row2">
                <td data-name="pic3">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/A2-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/A2-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td data-name="pic4">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/B2-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/B2-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-name="row3">
                <td data-name="pic5">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/A3-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/A3-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td data-name="pic6">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/B3-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/B3-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-name="row4">
                <td data-name="pic7">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/A4-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/A4-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td data-name="pic8">
                    <a class="openBox" data-source="split/B4-4096-0171.mp4">
                        <img src="thumb/B4-4096-0171.png">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

The black is the body background is the `body` tag, while the white is the `html` tag, so the table is, for some reason, going *outside* the body going by the way it looks. It *should* be no taller than the window based on my CSS, correct?

Comment: _“I'm trying to use a table as a replacement for an image map so that it can be responsive”_ – that doesn’t sound like a good idea at all to me; tables and responsive don’t go that well together. There’s plugins for that kind of stuff (like f.e. http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html). And if you don’t need “irregular” shapes for the links, but are fine with using rectangles only, then I’d rather use actual links, absolutely positioned on top of a responsive image, using percentages for the positioning and dimensions, that works quite well from my experience.

Comment: i agree with CBroe.  However, your problem seems like a classic issue with a container not recalculating size based on contents.  Often an overflow: hidden or clearfix class will help.

Comment: I see that you are loading images in your table, if they are big images they will definitely impact in the height of your table ... you will need to add some css to control the height of them

Comment: My guess is the images themselves are extending beyond 100%, but it's really hard to tell without some images of the size you used to experiment with. 
Try using chrome' or firefox's developer tools to determine the calculated size of each of the table elements as compared to the height of the image(s) used.

Comment: I have found and got working (or more accurately, the person I'm making the site for) actual image maps and got them working responsively though a jQuery plugin. @leo.fcx I did set the `img` tag, I just accidentally missed it while copying the CSS.